# Logging in fastapi: This event loop is already running

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have a FastAPI application. In this application I want to have a custom logger. In this logger I want to send async requests to some host.

I have an error:

> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

My code:

```
import asyncio
import functools

class HttpHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    Logging Handler for fluent.
    Sends HTTP POST requests 
    """
    def __init__(self, tag: str, host: str, port: int):
        self.tag = tag
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.run_forever()
    
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
    
    async def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        payload = {} # some data
        future = self.loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(requests.post, data={
            "url": self.host,
            "json": payload
        }))
        response = await future
```

In my fastapi app I want to use logger like this:

```
    @app.on_event("startup")
    async def startup():
        #replace fastapi handlers
        logger.handlers = ServiceLogger.get_logger_instance().handlers # special service that gives me custom logger

    @app.post("/some_url")
    async def foo(body=Depends(get_body)):
        logger.info("TEXT")
```

**UPDATE**:
I was trying to apply aiohttp library

```
async def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        payload = {
            ...
            "message": record.message # log message
        }
        await aiohttp.post(self.host, json=payload)
```

But looks like it's not working because I see warning

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'HttpHandler.emit' was never awaited
  self.emit(record)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Any reason for not using `aiohttp` and getting await/asyncio functionality out of the box?

Comment: I have to use fastapi. Can I use aiohttp with fastapi? What aiohttp objects should I use?

Comment: `aiohttp` is a replacement for `requests`, not for FastAPI - it's a async compatible HTTP client with an interface that's almost identical to `requests`. So `await aiohttp.post(self.host, json=payload)` - no need to handle any event loops yourself. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client.html

Comment: I was trying, but looks like I have to change every call of emit() function. See updated question

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Also, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804), which show how to properly make HTTP requests within a FastAPI application. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804) might prove helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your design is that you simply assume that the `emit` method when subclassing a logging handler can be an async method.

It is a sync method, and it is documented as so - the fact a few, very convenient, 3rdy party libraries can detect and switch automatically between sync and async methods does not mean "any Python method in ay framework can be either async or sync and everything will just work".

Since you are already under an asyncio loop, it is just a matter of writing it as a sync function, and create and submit to the loop any async tasks from inside it (without trying to directly await those). Just take some care so that you keep a hard-reference to these created tasks, and for they to clean-up after themselves when they are done. A set containing the active tasks will do.

```
class HttpHandler(logging.Handler):
    
    def __init__(self, tag: str, host: str, port: int):
        self.tag = tag
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        # NO! none of these - Just let the loop be handled by the framework (or awsgi server)
        # self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        # self.loop.run_forever()
        
        self.running_tasks = set()
    
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)

    # this _must_ be a synchronous, regular, method
    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        payload = {} # some data
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # retrieve the running loop here: no race condition upon app initialization;
                                         # + free up the awsgi server to restart/start new loops if it wants to. 
        async def aux(payload):
            return await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(requests.post, data={
            "url": self.host,
            "json": payload
            })))
        future = asyncio.create_task(aux(payload=payload))
        
        # wrapping the future in a task ensure it is scheduled in the running loop.
        self.running_tasks.add(future)
        # add a callback to remove the reference to the running task:
        future.add_done_callback(lambda task: self.running_tasks.remove(task))
```

Other than the remarks above, this way of doing things will actually take advantage of using aiohttp and httpx combined - your http-views won't have to  ẅait until logging is complete" to return, and the actual logging will be completed in background as your server is doing other stuff.

Your previous design tried to await for the aiohttp request meaning that any logging in an http view function you would be serving would delay the completion of the view until after it was done.

(I mean: it will work as is, with `requests`, but you can use `httpx` instead, and get rid of the `run_in_executor` part, just create an `httpx.post` call as a task (or better, a wrapper over it that can handle exception in the logging post itself)

Comment: Error:
```future = asyncio.create_task(loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(requests.post, data={
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.18/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 382, in create_task
    task = loop.create_task(coro)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.18/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 431, in create_task
    task = tasks.Task(coro, loop=self, name=name)
TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got <Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() ```

Comment: hm.. it looks like `create_task` can only take co-routines, and not futures - but `run_in_executor` won't schedule the execution . Just create a wrapper co-routine then: a simple `async def` co-routine function with a single line in it calling `await loop.run_in_executor` - and pass this wrapper to the `create_task`  call. I will change the code above.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) demonstrates how to achieve what OP is asking for.