# Async to sync decorator generates bugs

Tags: python, mongodb, asynchronous, fastapi

I have a fast api application that uses a mongoDB database and we use Beanie as an ODM. We like the asynchronous feature of beanie. But we want to wrap the asynchronous functions in synchronous functions. I have a decorator that transforms async functions into sync functions in python. But it does not seem to work

The decorator looks like this

```
def async_to_sync(async_func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        result = loop.run_until_complete(async_func(*args, **kwargs))
        loop.close()
        return result

    return wrapper
```

But with this decorator I get:

```
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1511, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1504, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1377, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_forever
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 518, in uvloop.loop.Loop._run
RuntimeError: this event loop is already running.
```

Then I tried with a decorator that looks like this

```
def async_to_sync(async_func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = asyncio.ensure_future(async_func(*args, **kwargs))
        return result

    return wrapper
```

But I get `pending tasks` from the object `Task` as result. Is there a way to make this decorator working?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) helpful

Comment: If you're using FastAPI, which is already async, why on earth would you want to run an async function synchronously?