# Run another service in fastapi and monitor its' startup and shutdown

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

I want to start a FastAPI service in Python and a Java service to communicate through HTTP. My idea is to use `subprocess` to call the Java startup script, and then monitor the logs of the Java service to determine whether the start/stop was successful. Since `subprocess` is a blocking task, I replaced `asyncio.subprocess_shell` is successful, but it does not wait for the Java service to start successfully, which is a danger in potential. I hope to use `asyncio.SubprocessProtocol` continuously monitors Java's startup logs until it outputs a successful string, but the `while` statement is prioritized, preventing the `await` from being executed and causing the process to freeze. Is there a way to give `startup_event` is a signal to not start successfully until the task is completed?

And here is my code.

```
import asyncio
import re
from logging import logger
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
transport = asyncio.SubprocessTransport()
protocal = asyncio.SubprocessProtocol()


class MyProtocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol):
    startup_str = re.compile("Server - Started")
    is_startup = False
    is_exited = False

    def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
        logger.info(data)
        super().pipe_data_received(fd, data)

        if not self.is_startup:
            if re.search(self.startup_str, str(data)):
                self.is_startup = True

    def pipe_connection_lost(self, fd, exc):
        if exc is None:
            logger.debug(f"Pipe {fd} Closed")
        else:
            logger.error(exc)
        super().pipe_connection_lost(fd, exc)

    def process_exited(self):
        logger.info("Process Exited")
        super().process_exited()
        self.is_exited = True


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    global transport, protocal
    transport, protocal = await loop.subprocess_shell(MyProtocol, "/start_java_server.sh")

    # Waiting Application startup complete.
    # while not self.protocal.is_startup:
    #     pass


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    global transport, protocal
    transport.close()
```

Comment: Related answers ma y be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FastAPI application will not start until `startup_event` completes.

So, just add a loop to the "startup_event" function and wait until your "Java service" starts:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    global transport, protocal
    transport, protocal = await loop.subprocess_shell(MyProtocol, "/start_java_server.sh")

    while not protocal.is_startup:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
```

But I would recommend you to use lifespan object instead of deprecated `startup_event`. And add `started_future` Future object as it's [shown in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#loop-subprocess-exec-and-subprocessprotocol):

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import re
from logging import getLogger
from fastapi import FastAPI

logger = getLogger(__name__)

transport: asyncio.SubprocessTransport
protocol: "MyProtocol"

class MyProtocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol):

    def __init__(self, started_future: asyncio.Future, exited_future: asyncio.Future):
        self.started_future = started_future
        self.exited_future = exited_future
        self.startup_str = re.compile("Server - Started")

    def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
        logger.info(data)
        super().pipe_data_received(fd, data)

        # if not self.started_future.result():
        if re.search(self.startup_str, str(data)):
            self.started_future.set_result(True)

    def pipe_connection_lost(self, fd, exc):
        if exc is None:
            logger.debug(f"Pipe {fd} Closed")
        else:
            logger.error(exc)
        super().pipe_connection_lost(fd, exc)

    def process_exited(self):
        logger.info("Process Exited")
        super().process_exited()
        self.exited_future.set_result(True)


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    global transport, protocol
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    started_future = asyncio.Future(loop=loop)
    exited_future = asyncio.Future(loop=loop)
    transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_shell(
        lambda: MyProtocol(started_future, exited_future),
        "/start_java_server.sh"
    )
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(started_future, timeout=5.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout!')

    yield
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(exited_future, timeout=5.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout!')
    transport.close()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
```