# "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed" when using unit IsolatedAsyncioTestCase to test fastapi routes

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, asynchronous, fastapi

Consider this mcve:

**requirements.txt:**

```
fastapi
httpx
motor
pydantic[email]
python-bsonjs
uvicorn==0.24.0
```

**main.py:**

```
import asyncio
import unittest
from typing import Optional

import motor.motor_asyncio
from bson import ObjectId
from fastapi import APIRouter, Body, FastAPI, HTTPException, Request, status
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, EmailStr, Field
from pydantic.functional_validators import BeforeValidator
from typing_extensions import Annotated

# -------- Model --------
PyObjectId = Annotated[str, BeforeValidator(str)]


class ItemModel(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[PyObjectId] = Field(alias="_id", default=None)
    name: str = Field(...)
    email: EmailStr = Field(...)
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        populate_by_name=True,
        arbitrary_types_allowed=True,
        json_schema_extra={
            "example": {"name": "Jane Doe", "email": "jdoe@example.com"}
        },
    )


# -------- Router --------
mcve_router = APIRouter()


@mcve_router.post(
    "",
    response_description="Add new item",
    response_model=ItemModel,
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
    response_model_by_alias=False,
)
async def create_item(request: Request, item: ItemModel = Body(...)):
    db_collection = request.app.db_collection
    new_bar = await db_collection.insert_one(
        item.model_dump(by_alias=True, exclude=["id"])
    )
    created_bar = await db_collection.find_one({"_id": new_bar.inserted_id})
    return created_bar


@mcve_router.get(
    "/{id}",
    response_description="Get a single item",
    response_model=ItemModel,
    response_model_by_alias=False,
)
async def show_item(request: Request, id: str):
    db_collection = request.app.db_collection
    if (item := await db_collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})) is not None:
        return item

    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"item {id} not found")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = FastAPI()
    app.include_router(mcve_router, tags=["item"], prefix="/item")
    app.db_client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(
        "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false"
    )
    app.db = app.db_client.mcve_db
    app.db_collection = app.db.get_collection("bars")

    class TestAsync(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
        async def asyncSetUp(self):
            self.client = TestClient(app)

        async def asyncTearDown(self):
            self.client.app.db_client.close()

        def run_async_test(self, coro):
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            return loop.run_until_complete(coro)

        def test_show_item(self):
            bar_data = {"name": "John Doe", "email": "johndoe@example.com"}
            create_response = self.client.post("/item", json=bar_data)
            self.assertEqual(create_response.status_code, 201)

            created_item_id = create_response.json().get("id")
            self.assertIsNotNone(created_item_id)

            response = self.client.get(f"/item/{created_item_id}")
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    unittest.main()
```

When I try to run it I'll get this crash:

```
(venv) d:\mcve>python mcve.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_show_item (__main__.TestBarRoutesAsync.test_show_item)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\software\python\3.11.3-amd64\Lib\unittest\async_case.py", line 90, in _callTestMethod
    if self._callMaybeAsync(method) is not None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\software\python\3.11.3-amd64\Lib\unittest\async_case.py", line 112, in _callMaybeAsync
    return self._asyncioRunner.run(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\software\python\3.11.3-amd64\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\software\python\3.11.3-amd64\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\mcve\mcve.py", line 87, in test_show_item
    response = self.client.get(f"/item/{created_item_id}")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\testclient.py", line 502, in get
    return super().get(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1055, in get
    return self.request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\testclient.py", line 468, in request
    return super().request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 828, in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 915, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 943, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 980, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1016, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\testclient.py", line 344, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\testclient.py", line 341, in handle_request
    portal.call(self.app, scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\anyio\from_thread.py", line 288, in call
    return cast(T_Retval, self.start_task_soon(func, *args).result())
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\software\python\3.11.3-amd64\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 456, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\software\python\3.11.3-amd64\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\anyio\from_thread.py", line 217, in _call_func
    retval = await retval_or_awaitable
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 116, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 55, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 44, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 746, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 288, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 75, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 55, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 44, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 70, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 299, in app
    raise e
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 294, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\mcve\mcve.py", line 57, in show_item
    if (item := await db_collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})) is not None:
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\motor\metaprogramming.py", line 75, in method
    return framework.run_on_executor(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\mcve\venv\Lib\site-packages\motor\frameworks\asyncio\__init__.py", line 85, in run_on_executor
    return loop.run_in_executor(_EXECUTOR, functools.partial(fn, *args, **kwargs))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\software\python\3.11.3-amd64\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 816, in run_in_executor
    self._check_closed()
  File "D:\software\python\3.11.3-amd64\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.074s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The line that's producing that crash is `response = self.client.get(f"/item/{created_item_id}")` but I don't understand what's the issue.

Btw, not interested on using pytest at all, the main purpose of this question is to figure what's wrong and how to fix the current mcve

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you are also facing issues while running FastAPI.

To solve the **unit test** issue, try creating a `test_app.py` file in your directory and paste the following code:

```
import asyncio
import unittest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from abhyas import app

class TestAsync(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def asyncSetUp(self):
        self.client = TestClient(app)

    async def asyncTearDown(self):
        self.client.app.db_client.close()

    async def run_async_test(self, coro):
        return asyncio.run(coro)

    async def test_show_item(self):
        async def test_logic():
            bar_data = {"name": "John Doe", "email": "johndoe@example.com"}
            create_response = await self.client.post("/item", json=bar_data)
            self.assertEqual(create_response.status_code, 201)

            created_item_id = create_response.json().get("id")
            self.assertIsNotNone(created_item_id)

            response = await self.client.get(f"/item/{created_item_id}")
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        self.run_async_test(test_logic)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

It directly utilizes `asyncio.run` for running asynchronous coroutines, and the test methods themselves are marked as asynchronous.

After separating the `unit test` code from the FastAPI application. The `mcve.py` will look like this:

```
from typing import Optional

import motor.motor_asyncio
import uvicorn
from bson import ObjectId
from fastapi import APIRouter, Body, FastAPI, HTTPException, Request, status
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, EmailStr, Field
from pydantic.functional_validators import BeforeValidator
from typing_extensions import Annotated

# -------- Model --------
PyObjectId = Annotated[str, BeforeValidator(str)]


class ItemModel(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[PyObjectId] = Field(alias="_id", default=None)
    name: str = Field(...)
    email: EmailStr = Field(...)
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        populate_by_name=True,
        arbitrary_types_allowed=True,
        json_schema_extra={
            "example": {"name": "Jane Doe", "email": "jdoe@example.com"}
        },
    )


# -------- Router --------
mcve_router = APIRouter()


@mcve_router.post(
    "",
    response_description="Add new item",
    response_model=ItemModel,
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
    response_model_by_alias=False,
)
async def create_item(request: Request, item: ItemModel = Body(...)):
    db_collection = request.app.db_collection
    new_bar = await db_collection.insert_one(
        item.model_dump(by_alias=True, exclude=["id"])
    )
    created_bar = await db_collection.find_one({"_id": new_bar.inserted_id})
    return created_bar


@mcve_router.get(
    "/{id}",
    response_description="Get a single item",
    response_model=ItemModel,
    response_model_by_alias=False,
)
async def show_item(request: Request, id: str):
    db_collection = request.app.db_collection
    if (item := await db_collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})) is not None:
        return item

    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"item {id} not found")


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(mcve_router, tags=["item"], prefix="/item")
app.db_client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(
    "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false"
)
app.db = app.db_client.mcve_db
app.db_collection = app.db.get_collection("bars")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("mcve:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

If you need help setting up MongoDB locally, you can refer to this [page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/installation/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an endpoint to match /item/{created_item_id} . However the one you have is /{id} . Therefore you're getting a covert 404 not found exception, that does not bubble up but still breaks the test scenario, causing the event loop to stop.