# Video streaming using Ngrok, FastAPI and OpenCV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, fastapi, ngrok

I used `Ngrok`, `fastapi` and OpenCV to upload video stream in Python.

It generates a random `URL` everytime.

Now I have a static `ngrok` domain. How do I implement that?

THE CODE I USED:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from pyngrok import ngrok
import cv2
import io
import threading
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()

def generate_frames():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Adjust the camera index as needed

    if not cap.isOpened():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Cannot open camera")

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            break

        _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame_bytes = buffer.tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame_bytes + b'\r\n')

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return StreamingResponse(generate_frames(), media_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")

def run_fastapi():
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

def expose_with_ngrok():
    public_url = ngrok.connect(8000)
    print(f" * ngrok tunnel \"{public_url}\" -> \"http://127.0.0.1:8000/\"")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Start FastAPI in a separate thread
    fastapi_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_fastapi)
    fastapi_thread.start()

    # Wait for FastAPI to be fully started
    ngrok_thread = threading.Timer(2, expose_with_ngrok)
    ngrok_thread.start()

    # Keep the main thread running
    fastapi_thread.join()
```

It works all fine just want to use my static domain instead of random domain.

Comment: On a side note, the way you start the two services might not be the most suited one. You mgiht find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) helpful that provides solutions on that topic.